# Could not find declaration module for file 'solc'

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs

[image]I was trying with a simple contract,when I do  "node compile.js" in my windows cmd it throws an error.I was using vscode it showing error in const solc = require('solc'),I installed everything perfectly but I don't know why the error occurs.

Comment: Hi there. How have you installed `solc` in your project? What are the contents of your `package.json` file?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying.In package.json file i have solc in dependencies even though i am getting this error

Comment: Okay - how have you installed `solc`? `require()` searches the modules installed in the project directory's `node_modules` folder, so this error is basically saying it's not there. Did you do `npm install solc`? I'd suggest just working at getting the examples from the NPM page working as a start -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc#example-usage-without-the-import-callback

Comment: I used Solidity compiler version 0.4.17 in my contract ,i also installed this in the project folder by "npm install --save solc@0.4.17".Still I was not able to tackle the error,is any other method is there? And I was able to find solc folder in node_modules directory.

Comment: Okay, in that case I'm not sure what's happening. Can you include the Node code that has the error? Note that version `0.4.17` is now 2 years old - you should think about using at least version `0.5.0` and above as there were various important changes.

Comment: const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc').default;

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Inbox.sol');

const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];                                                      This is the compile.js file when i place the mouse over require('solc') vscode displays could not find module declaration for file 'solc'

Comment: i installed and tried with the latest compiler version '0.5.2' still the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue .

1. npm uninstall solc
2. npm install --save solc@0.4.25

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Solidity version 0.4.17 is what im using. If you are getting this error, then you might likely have installed an unsupported version of solc.

You will need to do the following within the root of your project directory:

npm uninstall solc

rm -r node_modules

rm package-lock.json

npm install

npm install solc@0.4.17